# Excel: Use a complex model to calculate values on another sheet

Tags: excel

Let's say I created a complex financial model that uses 20 variable inputs to ultimately come up with a single result through a very large series of cells and formulas. I then want to make a summary rollup sheet that provides 7 or so sets of the 20 variables and the result value for each combination, but be able to tweak them and get the new result re-calculated. How can I have the model sheet be used as a calculation for the rollup sheet with 20 variables being passed?

For example, Model:

```
Var 1:  5
Var 2:  3
...
Var 20: 5

Result: 10843 (large multi-cell based model calculation)
```

Rollup:

```
Var 1:  5      6      2
Var 2:  3      3      5
...
Var 20: 5      6      3

Result: 10843  9834   5873
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with Excel's built in data tables!

Data tables take a a table with either one or two variable in the header row/column - and calculate the result of the workbook for each combination. Here is a simple model to show the concept:
[image]

To get this to work you need to:

1. Place a link to the final result your interested in into the top left cell of this table (in this case I place `=B3` in cell A5).
2. Enter the options for parameters 1 and 2 in the header row/column
3. Select the table
4. Click *Data* tab->*Data Tools*->*What-If-Analysis*->*Data Table*
5. Link the two parameters

Now in your case you have 20 parameters that you want to modify. You can easily do this the following way:
[image]

1. Insert a new "Current scenario" parameter - in the example this is the yellow cell V17.
2. Add another column to your table with the parameters for each scenario. In that column you select the right value for each parameter for the selected scenario. In my example, I used this formula:

   ```
   =INDEX($B5:$U5,$V$17)
   ```
3. Relink your model so that the parameters from this row are used for the calculation (in my example, the "model" simply returns the average of the parameters 1-10)
4. Build your data table:

   1. Link the result cell to the top left cell (here A22 is linked to V18)
   2. Enter the numbers from 1 to the count of your scenarios in the header column. (Note: you can also use names for the scenarios and in this table - you then need to modify the above `INDEX` formula to  `INDEX(...,MATCH(...))`)
   3. Select the table, i.e. the header row and another one (here range A22:U23)
   4. Add the data table. Note that you need to link the scenario ID in V17 as "Row input cell" (I always find this counter-intuitive). *Important:* You also need to provide a link for the empty "Column input cell", else the data table will return you the wrong result. In my example I linked cell W17, which is blank and unused throughout the model.

Done!

Comment: +1 Thank you for explaining this feature. I read more about it here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-HP010072656.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Because Peter Albert opened our eyes to Data Tables, I would also recommend the built-in What-If Analysis called [Scenarios](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-between-various-sets-of-values-by-using-scenarios-HP010072669.aspx?CTT=1).

While Data Tables are limited to one or two variables, Scenarios will manage up to 32. If you look at the Scenario Summary, about half way down the page, you will see a pre-built table that looks like it might fit the bill.